# How do I create a model in my Angular shared library?

Tags: angular, model, shared-libraries, angular-cli, angular14

I'm using Angular 14.  I want to create a project where I can house common models and services used by other projects.  I ran this command to create the scaffolding

```
$ ng generate library my-lib
```

This produced a directory structure that included

```
- tsconfig.json
- angular.json
- package.json
- package-lock.json
+ projects
    +   + my-lib
            + src
                ...
```

How do I generate a model class within that?  I tried the below

```
$ ng generate class=my-lib --type=model --project=my-lib/
An unhandled exception occurred: Schematic "class=my-lib" not found in collection "@schematics/angular".
See "C:\temp\ng-iUC12U\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

but I'm not sure what this error means or if I'm even generating a model the right way.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. There are no `=` used by the CLI. I believe this will do what you intended:

`ng generate class my-lib --type model --project finance-uilib-common-service/`

If you want to see what the changes will be first without having to create the files, use the `--dry-run` flag.

Comment: In my project directory, this is creating a file "src/lib/my-lib.my-product.model.ts.ts " (the parameter after class is getting prepended to the model file).  Is there any way to have my "my-product.model.ts" file created in a models directory (and also not have ".ts" appended twice)?

Comment: This answer worked for me - I'd refrain from naming the class the same as the library though, this may be confusing to the cli.